# Combine views in views.py into a single view?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am building a project in which I have a couple of views in my views.py that I want to combine in a dashboard format (4 views side by side).  They are sufficiently complex because each view takes in a number of variables and has a lot of logic server side, and I also intend to use them elsewhere alone.

The question I have is **what is the best way to combine separate views from views.py into a single view** if I want to create a dashboard view (ie. I have a base template with header/footer, and then 4 views embedded in that base).

My proof of concept was to call the view with the right variables and decode the rendered return, then pass it as a variable onto the template, and finally just insert it as safe code.  See below.  My gut tells me this is terrible practice, but I'm not sure the includes/extends system is appropriate for such a use.

**views.py**

```
def view1(request, r1_level, r2_level, d_level, call_code):
    ...
    return render(request,
        'modules/logic/levels/' + call_code + '.html',
        {
            'indicators': indicators,
            'd_level': d_level,
            'prof': prof,
            'a_flag': a_flag
        }
    )

def dashboard(request, level_code):
    view1 = view1(request, r1_level, r2_level, d_level, call_code).content.decode("utf-8")
    ...

    return render(request,
        'dashboard.html',
        {
            'view1': view1,
            ...
        }
    )
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<div id="site-wrapper" class="content">
  <div class='grid-container'>
    <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">

      <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-8">
        ...
      </div>

      <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-4">
        {{ view1 | safe }}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for reading through this mess!

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is possible, but you have to do a bit of a work around.

**views.py**

```
def build_view1_data(): # not a view, just a helper function
    dict = {}
    ... build logic here ...
    return dict

def dashboard_view(request):
    context_dict = {
        'view1': build_view1(),
        .... etc.
    }

    return render(request, 'template.html', context_dict)
```

Then you can access all your view1 data in the template with {{ view1.somedata }}. Furthermore, when you want to actually build view1, you can do the same thing as above, and call the build_view1_data function.

You can also build the templates so that you can add something like this in your dashboard template and your view1 template.

**dashboard.html**

```
 {% include 'view1.html' %}
```

That way you only have to write it once.